# Is there a way to make the panel calendar "functional" in Ubuntu 11.10?

Tags: 11.10, calendar

I'm using 11.10 and haven't ditched Unity, but I believe the calendar in the panel (the upper right of the screen) is part of Gnome.  Anyway, I can view the calendar and highlight a specific day but that's it.  It's not a shortcut to any calendar that you could do scheduling or anything. Am I missing some functions or is the extent of this calendars interactivity? If the calendar is really just for display, how do I change that to make it actually function with say, Google calendar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest installing evolution. You can do this by typing "sudo apt-get install evolution" (Without the "")
You can import your Gmail calendar then. Help can be found [here](http://www.ghacks.net/2009/05/14/connect-evolution-to-google-mail-and-calendar/)

The problem was caused by removing evolution mail client and replacing it with Thunderbird which isn't really "fully functional" yet.

Comment: Thanks. I'll prolly just wait to see how it works in 12.04. I didn't know for sure if it didn't work out-of-the-box or if I tinkered it to death.