# Standalone Calendar with Unity Integration

Tags: unity, software-recommendation, notification, calendar

I currently use Sunbird, and I like it for the most part, but its support is being dropped and it doesn't integrate with Unity. I'm looking for a calendar or personal organizer program which would run in the background as an app in the Unity system tray, and notify me of upcoming events without having to be explicitly opened.

However, I would rather not have this tethered to a mail client. An easy transition for data from Sunbird would be a bonus. Suggestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to make the panel calendar "funtional" in Ubuntu 11.10?](http://askubuntu.com/q/85659/35978).

Comment: @jwdinkc Certainly related to that question, but coming from the other direction. An answer to his question would not necessarily answer this question. I don't care whether the calendar integrates with the existing clock/calendar app or is a separate one, and he didn't specify that he wants it without a mail client, etc.

Comment: I don't know the exact answer, but i suggest [Mozilla Lightning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightning_%28software%29) as it is the descendant of Sunbird. Check out also [Calendaring software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calendaring_software)

Comment: @sindikat Thanks. I'm looking for a standalone application, though, which Lightning is not...it is "tightly integrated" in to Thunderbird.

Comment: lightning also only notifies you, when thunderbird is running and it doesn't integrate to the calendar in the panel and doesn't use notify-osd. your best bet would be evolution cause it's tightly integrated to unity...but then you have them problem of it being also a mail client which apparently you don't want

Comment: OP are you still looking for an answer? If so, you may need to repost your question as this is flagged for closure. Regards,

Comment: @user114117 You may post your information as an answer or a comment. It does not belong as an edit to the question—particularly since you are not the owner of the question. I'm surprised the reviewers approved it.

Answer (score 2):

Use Evolution Mail and Calendar. Integrates with Unity's Date & Time applet perfectly. Also it supports syncing with Google Calendar and other popular online calendar services.